# change tab text in monodevelop c#

Tags: c#, tabs, mono, widget, tabcontrol

I am currently building a web browser.

I am using a notebook widget as a tabcontrol.

But there is a problem: how do I change the text of a tab?

I have a custom widget that is inside each tab that is opened by the user. The custom widget is nothing but a webview on it. It just makes things easier, and I am able to control errors using this method as well.

Now, since a tab in the notebook is the parent of the custom widget, how can I change the text of the tab from the custom widget. I don't see a Text property in the Parent property.

Thanks for your help.

P.S. I am using MonoDevelop 2.6, Language: C#

Edit:

In my main main window, I have added this control to add my custom widget to my notebook (which I have renamed to TabControl):

```
// function to add a new tab
private void AddTab(string URL)
{
    // Create new label for the tab
    Label label = new Label();
    label.Text = "Loading...";
    // Add the page to the TabControl
    TabControl.AppendPage(control, label);
    // Show the TabControl and its children
    TabControl.ShowAll();

    // Navigate to the specified URL
    view.Open(URL);
}
```

And on my custom widget, which only contains a Webkit.WebView, I have got this:

using System; using WebKit; using Gtk;

```
public partial class WebControl : Gtk.Bin
{
    public WebView view = new WebView();

    public WebControl ()
    {
        this.Build();

        view.Open("http://www.google.com.au");

        this.Add(view);

        view.Show();
        view.ShowAll();

        this.Show();
        this.ShowAll();

        view.LoadFinished += new LoadFinishedHandler(viewLoadFinished);
    }

    protected void viewLoadFinished (object sender, WebKit.LoadFinishedArgs e)
    {
        // This is where I want to change the text of the tab, and the tab is the parent of this custom control
    }

    public WebView CurrentView
    {
        get { return view; }
    }
```

So, there is my code. I just can't find the property of the notebook's tab to change the text of the

Comment: show some code please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Gtk.Widget's .Parent property will obviously not have properties specific to the type of widget that the parent is, because it isn't cast to the actual widget type. You'll have to cast yourself.

Once you walk up the list of parents to the Gtk.Notebook, you can call `notebook.SetTabLabelText (this, "new text");` (or something like that, I may not have the name right as I do not have any code in front of me)